# XCode - Unable to profile my app

Tags: xcode, profiling

I cannot profile my app using `Instruments` because its menu item is disabled. Googling around, I see that the main reason is the executable in `Scheme` turned None, but my `Scheme` does not [image]

How can I fix this?

Note that my other projects will have `Product - Profile` still working. 
My XCode is 8.2.1.

Thanks

Comment: Could you show the settings for the ’Profile’ action instead of the ’Run’-action?

Comment: When you post, please read the descriptions of the tags you're using.

Comment: @Mats Thanks a lot! My `Scheme - Profile` does have problem. Its executable is `None`. After picking my app from the menu, `Menu - Profile` is back.